# How do remove trailing numbers in python

Tags: python

I am working on a python project and get a problem.

I have a for loop that makes a list with numbers. The problem is when I print out the list to check if the numbers are correct.

Some of the more simpler calculations are:
2.6 * 3 and 1.3 * 9

If you check with a calculator you should get 7.8 and 11.7, but I get 7.800000000000001 and 11.700000000000001

Which is not a big problem, but I don't like how it looks. (First world problem, I know)

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: These are not "trailing numbers" - the numbers you are working with are not sums of exact powers of two.

Comment: If you are using numpy, you can use `numpy.set_printoptions(precision=N)` to round the output to N digits. This only affects the displaying of the numbers, not the actual value and works only with arrays, not lists or single numbers

Answer (score 1):

Use string format?

```
print "%.2f" % (2.6 * 3)
```

The %.2f means print a float to 2dp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to display the output you want:

```
>>> print(format(2.6 * 3, ".1f"))
7.8
```

Here `".1f"` means "floating point number to one decimal place".

Answer (score 0):

You can use format print.

```
res = 2.6*3
"%0.2f" % res
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example with a list.

```
 >>> n = [1.9, 7.8 , 9,3.4]
 >>> print n
      [1.8999999999999999, 7.7999999999999998, 9, 3.3999999999999999]
 >>> twodecimals = ["%.2f" % v for v in n]
 >>> print twodecimals
      ['1.90', '7.80', '9.00', '3.40']
  >>> print twodecimals[0]
      1.90
```

`%.2f` means prints only 2 decimal points. Similarly, `.1f` means 1 decimal point and so on.